# Regular expression in JavaScript: Isolate a int value

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to isolate the second number in this plain text (not a HTML code, just an example):

```
Showing <span id="results_end">10</span> of <span id="results_total">55</span> items</div>
```

So my Regex expression should give back the number 55 only.

This is the closest I got on my own:

```
/l">(.*)</span>/g
```

However this still gives back the whole `l">61</span>` part, which is too much for my needs.

Any help by a regex guru would be welcome!

Comment: Please show your actual JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var match = /l">(.*)<\/span>/.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions aren't meant to parse HTML, although in a very simple case such as this one it would work.  A better way would be to use native JS functionality:

```
var inputString = 'Showing <span id="results_end">10</span> of <span id="results_total">55</span> items';

var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = inputString;

var num = parseInt(el.getElementById( 'results_total' ).innertext);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for  the intel, that's a more elegant way to do it for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group with the pattern `(\d+)` instead of `(.*)` if you only want to capture digits.